# undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass on uploading file into database using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, file-upload

Im making an application in rails and my upload is throwing an error. Here are the details. My photos_controller.rb

```
    def create

        @photo = Photo.new(params[:photo])

        respond_to do |format|
          if @photo.save
            format.html { redirect_to @photo, notice: 'Photo was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render json: @photo, status: :created, location: @photo }
          else
            format.html { render action: "new" }
            format.json { render json: @photo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
        end
```

my form

```
<%= f.file_field :binary_data %>
<%= f.submit %>
```

database model

```
      t.string :photon
      t.column :lat, :string
      t.column :lon, :string
      t.column :pname, :string
      t.column :uname, :string
      t.column :content_type, :string 
      t.column :filename, :string 
      t.column :binary_data, :binary 
      t.timestamps
```

I tried some ways which was mentioned in some blogs. None of them worked. 
Here is the full trace

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:25:in `block in initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:27:in `yield'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:27:in `default'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:27:in `block in initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:27:in `yield'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:27:in `default'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:27:in `block in initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:27:in `yield'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:27:in `default'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:27:in `block in initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:27:in `yield'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:27:in `default'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:27:in `block in initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:102:in `yield'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:102:in `default'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:102:in `accept'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:447:in `block in dump_ivars'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:445:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:445:in `dump_ivars'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:124:in `visit_Object'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:102:in `accept'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:66:in `push'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:242:in `dump'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/quoting.rb:38:in `quote'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:203:in `quote'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:8:in `block in to_sql'
arel (3.0.3) lib/arel/visitors/bind_visitor.rb:17:in `call'
arel (3.0.3) lib/arel/visitors/bind_visitor.rb:17:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_BindParam'
arel (3.0.3) lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:19:in `visit'
arel (3.0.3) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:111:in `block in visit_Arel_Nodes_Values'
arel (3.0.3) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:109:in `map'
arel (3.0.3) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:109:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_Values'
arel (3.0.3) lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:19:in `visit'
arel (3.0.3) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:74:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_InsertStatement'
arel (3.0.3) lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:19:in `visit'
arel (3.0.3) lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
arel (3.0.3) lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:19:in `accept'
arel (3.0.3) lib/arel/visitors/bind_visitor.rb:11:in `accept'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:7:in `to_sql'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:89:in `insert'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:14:in `insert'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/relation.rb:66:in `insert'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:363:in `create'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in `create'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:268:in `block in create'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__4454296851553403224__create__1976589364162331536__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_create_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:268:in `create'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:344:in `create_or_update'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:264:in `block in create_or_update'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__4454296851553403224__save__1976589364162331536__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_save_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:264:in `create_or_update'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:84:in `save'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in `save'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:241:in `block (2 levels) in save'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:295:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:241:in `block in save'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:252:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:240:in `save'
app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:47:in `block in create'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:278:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:278:in `retrieve_collector_from_mimes'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:194:in `respond_to'
app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:46:in `create'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__1057882058708114548__process_action__3391181575290593173__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:205:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:67:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:67:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:30:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:594:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__255478243604444547__call__1976589364162331536__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:61:in `call'
railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

parameters

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"1zvkibcE9YuaT2sR2ofHx06MlpH7JtK7QiK/sExTNVY=",
 "photo"=>{"binary_data"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fdc144411a8 @original_filename="1.jpg",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo[binary_data]\"; filename=\"1.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
 @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20140417-28258-142dwwo>>},
 "commit"=>"Create Photo"}
```

server log

```
Started POST "/photos" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-17 03:21:40 +0530
Processing by PhotosController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"1zvkibcE9YuaT2sR2ofHx06MlpH7JtK7QiK/sExTNVY=", "photo"=>{"binary_data"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fdc144411a8 @original_filename="1.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo[binary_data]\"; filename=\"1.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20140417-28258-142dwwo>>}, "commit"=>"Create Photo"}
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 23ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:47:in `block in create'
  app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:46:in `create'
```

Comment: Post your full error stack trace.

Comment: Do u have any  callbacks on Photo model (like after_save, after_create etc )? If yes, then please share them in the question.

Comment: nope. There is no callback..

Comment: Can you share the relevant server log from terminal where you are running the rails server.

Comment: If this is a simple picture attachment you should check out paperclip.

Comment: I did the upload with paperclip finally. Just want to know what is causing this problem.

Comment: I had this exact error when I moved from Rails 3.2.17 to Rails 3.2.17 :S