# undefined method `attr_accessible' while using paperclips for updating photo field in update form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My update form is giving me this error when I choose a new value for the :photo field and update it. It doesnt give an error when non-image fields like username, cellphone, or email are updated and saved. I'm using paperclip as the file attachment management gem.

```
end

attr_accessible :photo # this is where the error points to
has_attached_file :photo,
:styles => {
  :thumb=> "100x100#",
```

here is the full trace: http://pastie.org/private/etie0qfqujkvrzpetpuqw

Here is the edit.html.erb:

```
<h1>Add A teacher</h1>

<%= form_for @teacher, :url => { :action => 'update', :id => @teacher.id}, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
<table summary="teacher form fields">
   <tr>
     <th>First Name*</th>
     <td><%= f.text_field :firstname %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>Last Name*</th>
     <td><%= f.text_field :lastname %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>Email*</th>
     <td><%= f.email_field :email %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>Cellphone</th>
     <td><%= f.telephone_field :cellphone %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>Username*</th>
     <td><%= f.text_field :username %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <tr>
     <th>Password*</th>
     <td><%= f.password_field :password %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>Confirm Password*</th>
     <td><%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>Address Street#</th>
     <td><%= f.text_field :addr_streetno %></td>
     <th>Apt #</th>
     <td><%= f.number_field :addr_aptno %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>City</th>
     <td><%= f.text_field :addr_city %></td>
     <th>State</th>
     <td><%= f.text_field :addr_state %></td>
     <th>Zip</th>
     <td><%= f.number_field :addr_zip %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>Photo</th>
     <td><%= f.file_field :photo %></td>
   </tr>
</table>

   <%= f.submit 'Update teacher' %>
<% end %>

<% if @teacher.errors.any? %>
    <ul class="Signup_Errors">
    <% for message_error in @teacher.errors.full_messages %>
      <li>* <%= message_error %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Here is the controller:

```
class TeacherController < ApplicationController
  def index
      @teachers= Teacher.all 
  end

  def new
      @teacher = Teacher.new
  end

  def create
      @teacher = Teacher.new(teacher_params)
      if @teacher.save
        flash[:notice] = "Teacher created."
        redirect_to :action => 'index'
      else
        render :action => 'new'
      end
  end

  def edit
    @teacher = Teacher.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
     @teacher = Teacher.find(params[:id])
     # Update the object
     if @teacher.update_attributes(teacher_params)
       # If update succeeds, redirect to the list action
       flash[:notice] = "Teacher updated."
       redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @teacher.id
     else
       # If update fails, redisplay the form so user can fix problems
       render :action => 'edit'
     end
  end

  def show
    @teacher = Teacher.find(params[:id])
  end

private

    def teacher_params
      params.require(:teacher).permit(:firstname, 
                                      :lastname,  
                                      :email, 
                                      :cellphone, 
                                      :username, 
                                      :password,
                                      :password_confirmation,
                                      :addr_streetno, 
                                      :addr_aptno, 
                                      :addr_city, 
                                      :addr_state,
                                      :addr_zip, 
                                      :photo)
    end
end
```

Here is the model:

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :students

    has_secure_password

    EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\z/i
    CELLPHONE_REGEX = /\A([0-9]( |-)?)?(\(?[0-9]{3}\)?|[0-9]{3})( |-)?([0-9]{3}( |-)?[0-9]{4}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{7})\z/i
    validates :firstname, :presence => true
    validates :lastname, :presence => true   
    validates :username, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :length => { :in => 3..20 }
    validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :format => EMAIL_REGEX
    validates :cellphone, :presence => true, :format => CELLPHONE_REGEX
    [:addr_aptno, :addr_zip].each do |n|
        validates n, numericality: { only_integer: true, 
                                    :greater_than => 0,
                                    :allow_blank => true
                                   }
    end
    attr_accessible :photo
    has_attached_file :photo,
     :styles => {
      :thumb=> "100x100#",
      :small  => "150x150>",
      :medium => "300x300>",
      :large =>   "400x400>" }
end
```

Comment: Please show the full stack trace.

Comment: Here it is http://pastie.org/private/tupmyeph1levithw5talta

Comment: It looks like the same problem as this which was never resolved; the OP ended up using Paperclip instead -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23115216/undefined-method-name-for-nilnilclass-on-uploading-file-into-database-using-r

Comment: @gvermag Which gem are you using for uploading files? carrierwave or paperclip or something else?

Comment: @KirtiThorat I just wisened up the fact that I needed an attachment handling gem, so I installed the paperclips 4.1.1 gem and also Imagemagick using brew. Now, I am looking at how to use it. Let me update the issue after this.

Comment: @KirtiThorat I just updated the issue definition with the latest changes

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined method attr\_accessible error for User](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23743603/undefined-method-attr-accessible-error-for-user)

Comment: @ArupRakshit This is not a dup of the issue you mentioned. The solution was totally different. I have answered the question myself. Removing attr_accessible & restarting the rails server were part of the solution, but not the entire solution. In addition, I had to add :photo in the strong parameter assignment and also had to add add_attachment :teachers :photo in the migration file & run it. There were several pieces to it. Stackoverflow does not allow the original poster to write comments with code in it properly. Its an inconvenient feature.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer the Original Question**

> updating an image field gives NoMethodError undefined method `name'
>   for nil:NilClass in`update'

OP wasn't using amy gem to facilitate uploading files in the Rails application which was causing this issue. Suggested OP to use one of the well known gems **[Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)** or **[CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)**.

**Answer the Modified Question**

> undefined method `attr_accessible' while using paperclips for updating
>   photo field in update form

As you are using `Rails 4`, `attr_accessible :photo` will not work as it has been removed. Instead you would need to use `Strong Parameters` for attribute whitelisting which you are already doing by permitting `:photo` attribute in `teacher_params` method.

So, all you need to do is remove `attr_accessible :photo` from `Teacher` model.

Comment: Its not working. Still getting undefined method `has_attached_file'. Do I have to require any module in the code?

Comment: I would recommend you to read the [Paperclip Documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) and especially take a note of Migration. Also, make sure you `bundle install` and restart the server after adding the `paperclip` gem in `Gemfile`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Restarting the server and adding the migration did it for me (had to run it of course). Then I had to also add :photo_file_name in the strong parameter assignment list. Insert and update works, but the display does not work. Any ideas.

Comment: You are extending questions from original question. I would recommend you to post another question by giving specific error description and details. If my answer helped you to get through the original question then consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Actually, in the browser HTML source, the image is showing up as <td><img alt="Missing" src="/photos/original/missing.png" /></td>. I guess it didnt get saved properly

Comment: opened followup issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747889/paperclip-attachment-not-saving-to-database-broken-image-in-show-form

Comment: @KirtiThorat While you had already mentioned in one post these stuffs, why again here same answer. Rather you could close this one as a dup of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23743603/undefined-method-attr-accessible-error-for-user/23743692#23743692). Is not it good to decrease the load of same posts in SO ?

Comment: @gvermag Some of the SO readers(see comment above) are confused as to what was the question about. I updated my answer to reflect the two questions. May be you should update the question too with the actual question + modified question. This will help them to understand better.

Answer (score 0):

Adding restarting the rails server (since the paperclips gem was added) & adding add_attachment :, : to the migration file and running it, the following fields in the table (add_attachment :teachers :photo used run here)

```
t.string   "photo_file_name"
t.string   "photo_content_type"
t.integer  "photo_file_size"
t.datetime "photo_updated_at"
```

In addition, I had to add :photo in the strong parameter assignment call in the controller file and also had to add add_attachment :teachers :photo in the migration file & run it. There were several pieces to it.

Comment: So it worked... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747889/paperclip-attachment-not-saving-to-database-broken-image-in-show-form/23748940?noredirect=1#23748940