# Paperclip attachment not saving to database; broken image in show form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Problem:

Although the insert and update form don't give error while saving paperclip attachment, the display form is showing a broken image for the image. I have followed the paperclip documentation properly as far as possible.

PS: I don't see the :photo attribute as part of the insert statement in the web server logs.

The model has this:

```
has_attached_file :photo,
:styles => {
  :thumb=> "100x100#",
  :small  => "150x150>",
  :medium => "300x300>",
  :large =>   "400x400>" }
```

The new.html.erb has:

```
<%= form_for @teacher, :url => { :action => 'create'}, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
```

....
...

```
<tr>
  <th>Photo</th>
  <td><%= f.file_field :photo %></td>
</tr>
```

The edit.html.erb has:

```
<%= form_for @teacher, :url => { :action => 'update', :id => @teacher.id}, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
```

....
...

```
<tr>
  <th>Photo</th>
  <td><%= f.file_field :photo %></td>
</tr>
```

The controller has:

private

```
def teacher_params
  params.require(:teacher).permit(:firstname, 
                                  :lastname,  
                                  :email, 
                                  :cellphone, 
                                  :username, 
                                  :password,
                                  :password_confirmation,
                                  :addr_streetno, 
                                  :addr_aptno, 
                                  :addr_city, 
                                  :addr_state,
                                  :addr_zip, 
                                  :photo_file_name) # I had to change it from :photo. Was it the right thing to do. Otherwise, I think I was getting an error.
end
```

show.html.erb has:

```
  <td><%= image_tag @teacher.photo.url %></td>
```

Comment: What does your show.html.erb have?

Comment: it has      <td><%= image_tag @teacher.photo.url %></td>. But the problem seems to be that its not even getting stored somehow.

Comment: I don't see the :photo attribute as part of the insert statement in the web server logs. This is the problem i believe.

Answer (score 0):

In order to display the uploaded `:photo` on `show.html.erb` page, you would need to add the following code in that view:

```
<%= image_tag @teacher.photo.url %>
```

-OR-

```
<%= image_tag @teacher.photo.url(:style_name) %>
```

Where, replace `:style_name` with the specific style of image you would like to be displayed. For example: `:thumb`, `:small`, `:medium`, `:large` (As specified in `styles` Option of `has_attached_file`)

Also, in `teacher_params` you simply need to permit `:photo` attribute and not `:photo_file_name`.

Comment: SHow.heml.erb already has      <td><%= image_tag @teacher.photo.url %></td>

Comment: I had to change :photo_file_name to :photo in the teacher_params private method. Another change that I did was based on https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3. Instead of :thumb, :small, :medium, :large I specified it as thumb:, small:, medium:, large: in the has_attached_file directive in the model.

Comment: `:thumb=> "100x100#"` or `thumb: '100x100>'` are just old syntax and new syntax of hashes in Ruby. Using new syntax is always good but old syntax will not break your code(Just for your reference).

Answer (score 0):

Had to do this in the model file:

```
has_attached_file :photo, :styles => {
    thumb: '100x100>',
    small: '150x150>',
    medium: '300x300>',
    large: '400x400>' }

  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

In addition, did this change in the controller while doing strict parameter assignment:

```
def teacher_params
  params.require(:teacher).permit(:firstname, 
                                  :lastname,  
                                  :email, 
                                  :cellphone, 
                                  :username, 
                                  :password,
                                  :password_confirmation,
                                  :addr_streetno, 
                                  :addr_aptno, 
                                  :addr_city, 
                                  :addr_state,
                                  :addr_zip, 
                                  :photo)
```